How to use let/hstack to return all unique values that match to one criteria but not to another
I want to find all the values where only one of two conditions is true and the other is false.
I have a table (Firm___Released_Job_Mats) which contains many things but impotantly for this formula it contains 1) the job names ([Job-Suff]), 2) the operation numbers ([opernum]) and 3) the materials used in the job ([item]).
I want to make a list showing all of the materials used in one job (jorb1) that are not used in a second, comparison job (jorb2).  When I use the following code to look up the materials they share, it works perfectly:
    =LET(
jorb1,JORB1,
jorb2,JORB2,
jobs,Firm___Released_Job_Mats[Job-Suff],
opernum,Firm___Released_Job_Mats[oper_num],
materials,Firm___Released_Job_Mats[item],
filt,FILTER(materials,jorb1=jobs),
unsharedmats,UNIQUE(FILTER(materials,(ISNUMBER(MATCH(materials,filt,0)))*(jobs=jorb2)*(opernum>19)*(opernum<28))),
unsharedoper,BYROW(unsharedmats,LAMBDA(a,INDEX(Firm___Released_Job_Mats[oper_num],MATCH(1,((a=Firm___Released_Job_Mats[item])*(Firm___Released_Job_Mats[Job-Suff]=jorb1)),0)))),
HSTACK(unsharedmats,unsharedoper))

but when I change the "jobs=jorb2" portion to "jobs<>jorb2" part (within the line defining "unsharedmats") to find the list of materials that are exclusive to the first job, it instead gives me a list of all materials, including the materials they share.
I have been able to recreate the desired solution using two helper columns (Y & Z) by having the following in column Y:
=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Firm___Released_Job_Mats,JORB1=Firm___Released_Job_Mats[Job-Suff],""),8)

(column 8 is the [item] column)
and this in column Z:
=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Firm___Released_Job_Mats,JORB2=Firm___Released_Job_Mats[Job-Suff],""),8)
and then in column AA I can get the desired output with:
=FILTER(Z6#,NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Z6#,Y6#,0))))

(data starts in row 6 for the helper columns)
But ideally I want to get this all into my let function and I'm not sure how I can accomplish that.
I have tried combining these into my let by doing this:
=LET(
jorb1,JORB1,
jorb2,JORB2,
jobs,Firm___Released_Job_Mats[Job-Suff],
opernum,Firm___Released_Job_Mats[oper_num],
materials,Firm___Released_Job_Mats[item],
filt1,CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Firm___Released_Job_Mats,jorb1=jobs,""),8),
filt2,CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Firm___Released_Job_Mats,jorb2=jobs,""),8),
unsharedmats,UNIQUE(FILTER(filt1,NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(filt1,filt2,0)))*(opernum>19)*(opernum<28))),
unsharedoper,BYROW(unsharedmats,LAMBDA(a,INDEX(Firm___Released_Job_Mats[oper_num],MATCH(1,((a=Firm___Released_Job_Mats[item])*(Firm___Released_Job_Mats[Job-Suff]=jorb1)),0)))),
HSTACK(unsharedmats,unsharedoper))

but it is returning #VALUE!
Here is the simplest example of what I'm looking for that I know how to offer:


@ScottCraner see latest edit.  I (think) i already tried that

@ScottCraner I have added an extremely concise example.  I dont think I can simplify the task any further

Apparently it works if I remove the section where I multiply by opernum being between 20-27.  Not sure why it cares, but here we are.  I have it working now

It does not work because your operation is not filtered and not the same size as what is being passed to the MATCH:
=LET(
_rng,A1:C12,
jorb1,E1,
jorb2,F1,
jorb1_arr,FILTER(_rng,CHOOSECOLS(_rng,1)=jorb1),
jorb1_m,CHOOSECOLS(jorb1_arr,2),
jorb1_op,CHOOSECOLS(jorb1_arr,3),
jorb2_arr,FILTER(_rng,CHOOSECOLS(_rng,1)=jorb2),
jorb2_m,CHOOSECOLS(jorb2_arr,2),
jorb2_op,CHOOSECOLS(jorb2_arr,3),
jorb1_us,FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(jorb1_arr,2,3),(ISERROR(MATCH(jorb1_m,jorb2_m,0)))*(jorb1_op>19)*(jorb1_op<28),{"",""}),
jorb2_us,FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(jorb2_arr,2,3),(ISERROR(MATCH(jorb2_m,jorb1_m,0)))*(jorb2_op>19)*(jorb2_op<28),{"",""}),
VSTACK(HSTACK(jorb1,""),HSTACK("Material","Operation"),jorb1_us,HSTACK("Material","Operation"),HSTACK(jorb2,""),jorb2_us))



Shorter formulas:

[E2]=LET(a,A2:A16,b,B2:B16,f,FILTER(b,a=H1),FILTER(B2:C16,(a=E1)*ISNA(XMATCH(b,f))))
[H2]=LET(a,A2:A16,b,B2:B16,f,FILTER(b,a=E1),FILTER(B2:C16,(a=H1)*ISNA(XMATCH(b;f))))

Or combined formula
=LET(abc,A1:C16,j1b,E1,j2b,H1,a,TAKE(abc,,1),bc,TAKE(abc,,-2),b,TAKE(bc,,1),
  lam,LAMBDA(j1o,j2o,LET(f,FILTER(b,a=j2o),FILTER(bc,(a=j1o)*ISNA(XMATCH(b,f))))),
  VSTACK({"Material","Operation"},HSTACK(j1b,""),lam(j1b,j2b),HSTACK(j2b,""),lam(j2b,j1b))
)

